# Can we programmatically sort entries alphabetically in an excel sheet based on a certain column value

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi, jxl

I have *programmatically* created an excel sheet in which there are many rows of entries using **Apache POI**.

Is it possible to *programmatically* sort the entries in an excel sheet (**alphabetically**) based on the value in a certain column, by using any APIs? I need to implement this in an android app. So far I have observed that we can do this manually in the excel sheet, but is it possible to do this *programmatically*?

Any suggestions with regard to any **.jar** file (not necessarily **Apache POI**) will be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you insert the values alphabetically into excel rather than inserting and sorting the excel. Just a thought .It is an easy method indeed. As they say prevention is better than cure. Why to make the process complex. :)

Comment: Can you just write your own `Comparator` and sort the Java objects using `Collections.sort()`?

Comment: For your information , when you insert the values into excel using Apache POI , it will be stored in excel in the order you insert

Comment: @Stunner: My requirements have constrained me to resort to this approach. I had indeed thought about your suggestions beforehand, but they will not work for me :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache-POI sorting rows in excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134490/apache-poi-sorting-rows-in-excel)

Comment: Duplicate of here too https://stackoverflow.com/a/30240074/495157

Answer (score 1):

Apache POI does not have a convenient way of inserting rows: basically if you insert a row you have to shift down all following rows by 1. This is computationally expensive and tedious.

I therefore usually create a list of old rows, sort the rows using a custom comparator (which would then compare your certain column) and then create a new sheet where I would write the newly sorted list of rows in the right order. Then I would delete the old sheet and rename the new one using the old sheet's name.