# Sort Excel sheet using ApachePOI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have faced with a problem. I dont know how to sort my Excel File.

For example I have 3 columns. First two containing names, last one containing Date as String format.

I am need to sort it three times. First by first column, second by second column and last one by Date column.

I have to sort it three times, because first and second column will have the same values several times.

```
FirstName SecondName 00:01

FirstName SecondName 00:00

FirstName SecondName 00:02

ThirdName FourthName 00:01

ThirdName FourthName 00:02

ThirdName FourthName 00:00
```

This is should be looks like:

```
FirstName SecondName 00:00

FirstName SecondName 00:01

FirstName SecondName 00:02

ThirdName FourthName 00:00

ThirdName FourthName 00:01

ThirdName FourthName 00:02
```

Is anybody have faced with the same problem ?

Comment: Take a look at this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26718371/xssfsheet-apache-poi-sorting-and-filtering

Comment: I've already try it.Seems like aspose-cell is broken. workbook.getDataSorter() is not working.