# Is it a good practice to make a DAO class Comparable type

Tags: java, excel, hibernate, comparable

This is my sample mapping in hibernate

```
class ApplnDoc {
    AdmAppln admAppln;
    // getters and setters
}
```

---

```
class AdmAppln {
    Set<Student> student;
    // getters and setters
}
```

---

```
class Student {
    int id;
    String registerNo;
    AdmAppln admAppln;
    // getters and setters
}
```

In `ApplnDoc` table we are storing images of all candidates. `AdmAppln` is for storing admission details, `Student` is for storing student details. Even if `AdmAppln` is having a `Set` of `Student`, only one record of `Student` will be present for a particular `AdmAppln` `id` (under one AdmAppln only one Student).

Now I want to write few data from to these tables, into an `Excel` file, whose records must be sorted in the order of `registerNo` (if it is present), otherwise using `id` of the `Student`. We are using `XSSFWorkbook` class under `org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel` package for doing operations on `Excel` sheet. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26718371/xssfsheet-apache-poi-sorting-and-filtering) I found a way to sort the excel sheet, but I tried and found a way in code itself using `Comparable` interface.

This is what I did in `ApplnDoc` class

```
public int compareTo(ApplnDoc otherData) {
    if(new ArrayList<Student>(this.admAppln.getStudents()).get(0).getRegisterNo() != null && 
       !new ArrayList<Student>(this.admAppln.getStudents()).get(0).getRegisterNo().isEmpty() &&
       new ArrayList<Student>(otherData.admAppln.getStudents()).get(0).getRegisterNo() != null && 
       !new ArrayList<Student>(otherData.admAppln.getStudents()).get(0).getRegisterNo().isEmpty()) {

            return new ArrayList<Student>(this.admAppln.getStudents()).get(0).getRegisterNo()
                   .compareTo
                   (new ArrayList<Student>(otherData.admAppln.getStudents()).get(0).getRegisterNo());
    } else {
            return new ArrayList<Student>(this.admAppln.getStudents()).get(0).getId() -
                   new ArrayList<Student>(otherData.admAppln.getStudents()).get(0).getId();
    }
}
```

Since there is no `get()` method in `Set` interface the only way to get `Student`'s `registerNo` from `AdmAppln` was to convert it to a list. Then I sorted the list and then it was iterated to generate the excel file.

Is the above mentioned comparison mechanism a proper one or is there a better way? Why I am asking this question because when the Hibernate session is closed and in my `compareTo` if I'm accessing the child table columns, then I will be getting `Invocation` exception.

Comment: "the only way ... was to convert it to a list" `set.iterator().next()` is easier, since you're always accessing the first element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some thing worth discussing here:

1-

> Even if AdmAppln is having a Set of Student, only one record of
>   Student will be present for a particular AdmAppln

Why?
is this something you have no control over or is there any particular reason to keep a set where is not needed? (also im assuming a `@OneToMany` instead of a `@OneToOne` mapping)

2-

This lead to the child object beig lazy fetched (**N.B** this is an assumption since you didn't post relevant code about mappings or how you fetch the entity from db).

This means that you have to either switch to eager fetching in the entity (unrecommended) or specify it when fetching the entities

3-

Also please refactor that compareTo and use variables

```
public int compareTo(ApplnDoc otherData) {
Student thisStudent = new ArrayList<>(this.admAppln.getStudents()).get(0);
Student otherStudent = new ArrayList<>(otherData.admAppln.getStudents()).get(0);
    if(thisStudent.getRegisterNo() != null && 
       !thisStudent.getRegisterNo().isEmpty() &&
       otherStudent.getRegisterNo() != null && 
       !otherStudent.getRegisterNo().isEmpty()) {
           return thisStudent.getRegisterNo().compareTo(otherStudent.getRegisterNo());
    } else {
           return thisStudent.getId() - otherStudent.getId();
    }
}
```

While nothing wrong with that comparison mechanism (except the NullPointer if you have an empty `Set` of student) you should use the database ordering when querying.

If you still want to compare that way you just have to make sure you have everything you need fetched before closing the session.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the entire object tree before closing the session else you will get Exception. By the way you can always sort records with the query itself.