# Sorting of excel data using java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to sort excel sheet data alphabetically for particular column.  Currently I am writing java code to parse excel using apache poi library and get data in array and after that perform sorting on that data and again create new excel.

Is there any way to achieve it in simplest way in java?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache-POI sorting rows in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134490/apache-poi-sorting-rows-in-excel)

Comment: I got an idea how to fix. Thanks!

Comment: @Amongalen Yes answer you share helped me. Thanks for sharing!